# Webservice Returns Data All On One Line

Tags: c#, asmx

So I have a basic web service that is grabbing data from a MSSQL database. It works as it's supposed to in terms of SQL connections and queries however, I would like to know if it's possible to have the data displayed a little more elegantly. My goal is to return one name on each line but the web service just spits it all out between string tags  and all on one line. I'm EXTREMELY new to C# and ASP.NET and am amazed I made it this far. I just need to format the data in a more pleasant way if possible.

Here is my Code

```
namespace CustomerService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX,  uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {


    [WebMethod]
    //create new webMethod to get names
    public string getNames()
    {
        int size = DataHelper.name().Count();
        string[] names = new string[size];
        names = DataHelper.name();

        return toString(names);
    }

    //take array passed in and convert to one single string
    public string toString(string[] names)
    {
        int size = names.Count();
        string[] nameArray = new string[size];
        nameArray = names;
        string output = "";

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            output = output + "\n" + nameArray[x];
        }

        return output;

    }
}
}
```

And then the DataHelper service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CustomerService
{
    public class DataHelper
    {
    //create method to get names from customer DB
    public static string[] name()
    {
        string currentName ="";
        string[] names = new string[100];
        double checkingBal;
        double savingsBal;
        double cdBal;
        double mmBal;

        //create connection
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=STE2074;Initial Catalog=ATMWeb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=stp;Password=stp48329");

        //create command to get names
        string sqlString = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
        conn.Open();
        int x = 0;

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                currentName = reader["firstName"].ToString();
                names[x] = currentName;
                x++;
            }
            //close connections
            conn.Close();
            reader.Close();

            return names;
        }  

    }
}
```

And this is the final result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> Stephen lisa steve kyle s Lisa steven Customer   chelsea jon karen jessica meagan </string>
```

I would like a new line after each name...is this possible?

Comment: XML does not support whitespace.  (except with `xml:space`)

Comment: why not return a collection?! It's quite obvious here.

Comment: How would one go about returning a collection here. Sorry...once again, I'm VERY new lol

Comment: How are you _rendering_ the result to the viewer/user (_assuming_ you want something _other_ than XML)?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Is there someone who can help you? You have a large number of problems with that code. Briefly, you need `using` blocks around the `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection`, you should be storing your data in a `List<string>` instead of an array, and there's no value in doing `string[] names= new string[size];` since `names` is overwritten in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and return that.

```
PUBLIC Class MyOldStringNames
{
   property string NameHolder { get; set; }
}
End Class

List<MyOldStringNames> myListOfOldStringNames = new List<MyOldStringNames>();
For Each item in names 
   MyOldStringNames myItemToAdd = new MyOldStringNames() { NameHolder = item.toString() };
   myListOfOldStringNames.add(myItemToAdd);
End

return myListOfOldStringNames;
```

Of course your method would then be something like this. :

```
public List<MyOldStringNames> getNames()
    {
        int size = DataHelper.name().Count();
        string[] names = new string[size];
        names = DataHelper.name();

        //Do stuff above

        //return data as shown above;
    }
```

Comment: Is that class declaration for VB? I'm looking for equivalent in C#. When I try to create that class in C#, It won't compile. Here's what I did in C#: public class MyOldStringNames{
   string NameHolder { get; set; }
}

Comment: i just wrote it on the fly, it was missing brackets which i have added

Comment: thanks a ton! I'm almost there however I get an error: "Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyOldStringNames>' is less accessible than method 'CustomerService.Service1.getNames()"

Comment: Sorry had declare class as public as displayed above.

Comment: yea sorry...i tried that originally and it wasn't working so I went ahead and posted that comment but then i realized Visual Studio is dumb and I needed to clean the project for it to remove the error. Thanks A ton! Works exactly how i wanted